# How to write 'rostopic echo' in bash?

Tags: bash, ros

I am new to ROS and Bash scripting. I am trying to use the command **rostopic echo /topic name** in a bash file but my bash file is taking echo as its own echo, not the one in rostopic command. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Following is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
source '----/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash'
if [ $1 == 1 ]
then
    echo "$2"
    topiclist=$(rostopic echo /topic name)
    echo "$topiclist"
fi
```

Comment: The `source`d file name is pretty unusual; do you really have a directory with the name `----` in it?  What is in that `setup.bash` file?  It isn't clear if you really need `rostopic echo /topic $2` — which would vary the output depending on the arguments to your shell script.  Have you looked at the documentation for [`rostopic echo`](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_echo)?  It looks to me like you need `rostopic echo /$2` (to match `rostopic echo /topic_name`) in your script — so when you run `bash your-script.sh 1 chipmunks` it will report on 'chipmunks'.

Answer (score 0):

With some interpretation of what you might want to achieve, consider something like this (change paths, topic names accordingly):

```
#!/bin/bash
source '/home/yourUsername/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash'
if [ "$1" = "1" ];
then
    echo "Available topics"
    topiclist=$(rostopic list)
    echo "$topiclist"
    echo "Echoing topic $2"
    rostopic echo $2
fi
```

I'm not sure why you would want the first `if` statement. At the moment it checks whether you called the script with a `1` as the first argument, like so:

```
./bashEcho 1 myTopic
```

Also, note that this script will not terminate under normal circumstances. You have to press `ctrl+c` to stop the `rostopic echo` process.